# Display result of File Upload using Coldfusion.Navigation?

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion

I want to use a single home page where I will display an upload form (which is in another file). After uploading (action file result) I want to show the result of upload on the same page.

These are my three files:

**index.cfm**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <cfajaximport tags="CFFORM">
</head>
<body>
    <cfdiv id="Main" style="width:1000px; height:600px" >
        <cfdiv id="Options" style=" width:100%;height:20%" >
            Welcome Admin, <a href="javascript:ColdFusion.navigate('FileUpload.cfm','Content')" class="settings">Update  </a><a href="#" class="logout">Logout</a>
        </cfdiv>
        <cfdiv id="Content" style=" width:100%;height:80%">
            <h2>Here Goes Form and FileUploading</h2>
        </cfdiv>
    </cfdiv>
</body>
</html>
```

**FileUpload.cfm**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload A File</title>
</head>
<body >       
    <cflayout type="vbox" name="layout1">
        <cflayoutarea>
            <cfform  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="FileReceiver.cfm" >
                File To Upload:
                <cfinput type="file" name="Filename" size="50" >
                <br/>       
                <cfinput type="submit" name="UploadFile" value="UPLOAD THIS FILE">
                <br/>
            </cfform>
       </cflayoutarea>
       <cflayoutarea>       
       <table border="1" >
       <tr>
          <th >
               Directory Information
          </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <cfoutput >
               CurrectDirectory Path: #getdirectoryFromPath(expandPath("index.cfm"))#
               </cfoutput>
           </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </cflayoutarea>
   </cflayout>
</body>
</html>
```

**FileReceiver.cfm**

```
<cfif isdefined('UploadFile')  >
    <cfoutput >
        <cffile nameconflict="makeunique"
            action="upload"
            filefield="Form.Filename"
            destination="#getdirectoryFromPath(expandPath("index.cfm"))#" > 
            <!--- or destination="c:\Upload\"--->
        File upload was successful!

    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

When I click on "update link", the index page shows the FileUpload.cfm page in one of its containers. But when uploading file I always get an error message:

> Error retrieving markup for element cf_layoutarea736558924094373 :
>   Invalid content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8. [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL
>   parameters to see more information]

Kindly help me do it the right way, as I am unable to figure out the problem.

Comment: Is there a cffile tag you aren't showing us?

Answer (score 0):

In what is likely a mistyped cffile tag, you have this:

```
filefield="Form.Filename"
```

The [documentation for cffile](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_10.html), suggests that you should just just have the name of the form field, without the qualification.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but there seems no issue with this parameter as we have to pass a form field but with out pound ## sign.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not getting your Form scope values actually.
To upload a file, you have used multipart/form-data which are correct and also default value for method attribute in cfform is POST which also looks ok.

Probably issue is because of CFFileNonMultipartException.

Dump FORM scope before Upload code to check you are getting all form values or not on filereciever.cfm.

You can also try without cfform

```
<form action="FileReceiver.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="Filename">
<input type="submit" name="UploadFile" value="UPLOAD THIS FILE">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks Sam, it worked by replacing <cfform> with html <form> and <cfinput> with <input>. but why i was using <cfform> because i wanted to show the returned loadsuccess message in the same container where cfform is, actually as i read cfform submission shows the result in the container where it is whereas html form will take you to the new page... can i still do it,in what way ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dharmesh, you can do bit trick here. Get rid of fileReciever.cfm page. Add this code in index.cfm

```
 <cfif structKeyExists(FORM,"filename")> 
    <cffile action="upload" filefield="Form.Filename" destination="#getdirectoryFromPath(expandPath("index.cfm"))#" result = "fileUploaded"> 
    <cfif isDefined("fileUploaded") AND fileUploaded.FILEWASSAVED EQ "yes"> 
       Success
    </cfif> 
</cfif>
```

and submit your form to index.cfm not on fileReceiver.cfm